# How I can set app variables in Rails app by ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

Now, in my application, variables are stored in an env file and are immutable. Can I use ActiveAdmin to change them dynamically to the admin panel?

Comment: What do you mean by "change them dynamically to the admin panel?" You want their value to be different only in the admin panel?

Comment: @kkp I have an API for the service. This API uses the gem to access and interact with the service. I want to be able to dynamically change api keys in my app.
Now its looks like:
`config.api_variable = ENV['API_VARIABLES']&.split`

Comment: is the `config` a snipper from application.rb or a specific environment file like development.rb etc? If yes, then it can be accessed and modifed for sure, but it is highly unrecommended. 
A problem with modyfing those variables is that if server shuts down and resets, a deploy happens etc, the changes are lost, the app starts again the sets those values anew, and the user would have to go and modify by hand again. 
It does not sound like the api keys are used for credentials? Maybe simply storing them as app variables is not the best place to hold this data?

Comment: @kkp this part of the code is taken from the gem initializer, like ActionMailer

Comment: If you need to make the configuration user modifyable you would need some sort of persistent storage such as storing the user settings in the database. The crux really is that initialization files are read at startup so the configuration won't be updated until the server restarts in many cases. Configuration of Rails is really largely a developer concern.